# Validate .editorconfig file using Github Action

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, github-actions, editorconfig

I want to make sure that any pull request in my Github repo follows the rules defined in .editorconfig (ASp.NET Core 5 C# project). I have found https://github.com/github/super-linter to lint the code using,

I have added the below linter.yml file in my workflow,

```yaml
---
###########################
###########################
## Linter GitHub Actions ##
###########################
###########################
name: Lint Code Base

#
# Documentation:
# https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions
#

#############################
# Start the job on all push #
#############################
on:
    push:
    branches-ignore: [main]
    # Remove the line above to run when pushing to main
    pull_request:
    branches: [main]

###############
# Set the Job #
###############
jobs:
    build:
    # Name the Job
    name: Lint Code Base
    # Set the agent to run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    ##################
    # Load all steps #
    ##################
    steps:
        ##########################
        # Checkout the code base #
        ##########################
        - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            # Full git history is needed to get a proper list of changed files within `super-linter`
            fetch-depth: 0

        ################################
        # Run Linter against codebase #
        ################################
        - name: Lint Code Base
        uses: github/super-linter@v4
        env:
            VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
            DEFAULT_BRANCH: main
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

It is successful but I don't see it is validating the .editorconfig rules in the root of the Github repository? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the [Environment Variables](https://github.com/github/super-linter#environment-variables) from the Super Linter Github Action, the default value for the **EDITORCONFIG_FILE_NAME** file is `.ecrc`.

Therefore, if your file's name is `.editorconfig` you'll have to add it to the *action arguments list* with something like:

```yaml
- name: Lint Code Base
  uses: github/super-linter@v4
  env:
    VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
    DEFAULT_BRANCH: main
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    EDITORCONFIG_FILE_NAME: .editorconfig
```

Recognizing this file, the Super Linter action will use the [editorconfig-checker](https://github.com/editorconfig-checker/editorconfig-checker) repository to check it.

**EDIT:** Based on comments, `dotnet-format` used by super linter also automatically uses the `.editorconf` file. If you want to check it usung this linter, no need to set **EDITORCONFIG_FILE_NAME**. Only, set `VALIDATE_CSHARP: true`

Comment: The objective is just to check the editorconfig file, it doesn't check for any programming language (but super-linter does! )

Comment: Thanks. I found that dotnet-format used by super linter automatically uses the .editorconf file. So, no need to set EDITORCONFIG_FILE_NAME. Only, set `VALIDATE_CSHARP: true`